# How to reset time parameter in Calendar object after reseting other fields?

Tags: java, android

I get the current `Calendar` object and log its value

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Log.v(TAG,now.toString())
```

I set the time on `now` and log the value

```
now.set(Calendar.HOUR, 20 % 12);
now.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,20);
now.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
now.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
Log.v(TAG,now.toString())
```

When I make a side by side comparison of the two logs, I see a difference

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1498086510685,areFieldsSet=true... 
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false...
```

All other fields appear to be the same

I guess I have two questions

1. How do I set `time` to it's correct value?
2. Will `areFieldsSet` be set automatically if I reset the `time` paramter?

Answer (score 1):

If you had read the Javadocs for `java.util.Calendar`, which you should do, you would have seen

> `set(f, value)` changes calendar field `f` to `value`. In addition, it sets an internal member variable to indicate that calendar field `f` has been changed. Although calendar field `f` is changed immediately, the calendar's `time` value in milliseconds is not recomputed until the next call to `get()`, `getTime()`, `getTimeInMillis()`, `add()`, or `roll()` is made.

Invoke one of the indicated functions.